# order of matrix

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $H$ denote the group of all $2\times 2$ invertible matrices over $\mathbb Z_5$ under usual matrix multiplication. Then the order of the matrix
                $$
                  \begin{bmatrix}
                   2&3\\
                   1&2\\
                  \end{bmatrix}
                $$
in $H$ is--?

It means we have to find order, i.e to which power we should raise this matrix to get an identity matrix. 
If we raise its power to $3$, we'll get the identity matrix. 
or can we consider this matrix as $SL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$ group and calculate its order by the formula $[(p^n-1)(p^n-p)...(p^n-p^{n-1})]/(p-1)$
which method is correct?

Is there any other direct formula to calculate that?

Comment: Your formula is for the order of the group, not for the order of an element of the group.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying what i was assuming wrong. So correct way to find the order is to raise the power of matrix to get an identity matrix?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the only way, and you have already done this it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you may observe that the characteristic polynomial of your matrix $M$ is $X^2 - Tr(M)X + det(M)$, that is $X^2 -4X +1$, or $X^2 + X + 1$. It follows that $M^2 +M+1 = 0$, whence $M^3 -1=0$.

Comment: Than you for the answer. can you please explain how we got X^2 +X+1 after X^2- 4X+1 and then M^3 -1 =0?

Comment: @SonaliJain $\;-4=1\pmod5\;$ , and $\;M^3-1=(M-1)(M^2+M+1)\;$